# Reason for high CPU time when executing fio

Tags: ubuntu, performance, io

After weeks of troubleshooting some performance issues I have on my VPS running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, I am getting closer to the conclusion that the problem is related to IO.

When I have a considerable number of files that need to be access, the CPU spikes up to 100%. However, there is no IOWAIT, so it seems that for some reason it is the CPU that is not coping.

Using `fio` to do a random read test I managed to gather this output. On other machines (my personal Ubuntu for example), I noticed that the CPU time to do exactly the same test is much much lower, a small fraction. Are the times below normal? If not what could be the reason? Could it be that the virtualisation process is taxing the CPU too much when compared to native disk access?

```
random-read: (g=0): rw=randread, bs=4K-4K/4K-4K, ioengine=sync, iodepth=1
fio 1.59
Starting 1 process
random-read: Laying out IO file(s) (1 file(s) / 128MB)
Jobs: 1 (f=1): [r] [100.0% done] [12185K/0K /s] [2975 /0  iops] [eta 00m:00s]
random-read: (groupid=0, jobs=1): err= 0: pid=24264
  read : io=131072KB, bw=10298KB/s, iops=2574 , runt= 12728msec
    clat (usec): min=119 , max=162219 , avg=380.34, stdev=957.37
     lat (usec): min=119 , max=162219 , avg=380.89, stdev=957.40
    bw (KB/s) : min= 7200, max=13424, per=99.89%, avg=10285.72, stdev=1608.68
  cpu          : usr=2.80%, sys=18.65%, ctx=33511, majf=0, minf=23
  IO depths    : 1=100.0%, 2=0.0%, 4=0.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     issued r/w/d: total=32768/0/0, short=0/0/0
     lat (usec): 250=45.57%, 500=37.17%, 750=3.41%, 1000=7.83%
     lat (msec): 2=5.67%, 4=0.27%, 10=0.08%, 20=0.01%, 250=0.01%

Run status group 0 (all jobs):
   READ: io=131072KB, aggrb=10297KB/s, minb=10545KB/s, maxb=10545KB/s, mint=12728msec, maxt=12728msec
```